# Eclipse Luna default dark theme: XML colors

Tags: android, xml, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I'm using the new Dark theme included with Eclipse Luna and it's great except for XML files:

[image: XML editor hard to see font]

I've read that I can use the Eclipse Color Themes plugin, but I would like to keep the color scheme for the editors, while only changing the XML.

Is there another way of changing XML editor colors?

Comment: You mean other than its `Syntax Coloring` preference page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window/Preferences/XML/XML Files/Editor/Syntax Coloring/Content